# How to limit number of displayed values of the field with view in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

i have field_images filed in my custom node type. This field can have unlimited number of values (images). How can i set up the limit of displayed values of this field in Views in Drupal 7? I know it is possible in Drupal 6, but can't find how to do it in 7.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue fixed in dev branch.